# Varnish - Prevent Custom Block Caching

Tags: full-page-cache, varnish

I'm trying to exclude my custom block from Magento cache (Varnish) but I'm really struggling to figure it out ...I've spent hours trying.

Here's the custom blockL

```
{{block type="core/template" name="supplier.delivery" template="myphp/delivery.phtml"}}
```

and here's what I've entered in local.xml:

```
    <reference name="supplier.delivery">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <scope>page</scope>
            <registry_keys>
                <current_category/>
            </registry_keys>
        </params>
    </action>
</reference>
```

But it doesn't appear to work. Any help would really be appreciated. I've read all the ESI info I can find.

Thanks
Chris

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be affected by Turpentine (or the module you use) layout, you'd place your block in layout files also, not as a content loaded in CMS (or custom layout in backoffice) entities

**update**

Instead of loading your block in a CMS block, page, etc... or a Custom Layout update in backoffice you'd place it in the relevant layout file in **app/design/frontend**

For instance, as a generic example: let's say you want your block to be rendered in checkout/cart page

Edit your **app/desing/frontend/XXX/XXX/checkout.xml** file & define your block inside checkout_cart_index content tag

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
...
   <reference name="content">
   ...
       <block type="core/template" name="supplier.delivery" as="supplier.delivery" template="myphp/delivery.phtml" />
```

You'd then load your block in checkout/cart.phtml template, calling `echo $this->getChildHtml('supplier.delivery');`

Then, open your **app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/turpentine_esi.xml** layout file, and add your code there

```
<reference name="supplier.delivery">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <scope>page</scope>
            <registry_keys>
                <current_category/>
            </registry_keys>
        </params>
    </action>
</reference>
```

It's not required to use turpentine layout file to place your code, but it is safer, as Magento loads layout files in some order, so it is possible that ESI definition won't work if you use a different file than the provided by the module

I mean, technically you could add Turpentine methods directly in your block definition...

```
<block type="core/template" name="supplier.delivery" as="supplier.delivery" template="myphp/delivery.phtml">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <scope>page</scope>
            <registry_keys>
                <current_category/>
            </registry_keys>
        </params>
    </action>
</block>
```

But this could work, or not... so it is better to use the *long* approach

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your answer. Could you explain where you mean? I've added it to the /layout/local.xml

Comment: I've updated the answer, take a look

Comment: Perfect! I applied this ....and also disabled HTML Blocks in cache management (standard cache in magento) it now works fine. Thanks!